# Is there a way to get an email when your HTML5 site goes down like Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, server

I have wordpress sites that go down at around 12am because of my web host provider. I get emails every time they shut down. With my HTML5 sites I do not know if you can do the same thing? Is there a free service or something I can make from scratch that can do the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless the host itself is going to notify you of an outage, your only option is to periodically access the page from another host and report any problems with that access.  Any service which allows you to run a background 24/7 should do the job.

Comment: My host does not tell me that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a service like [this one](https://www.statuscake.com/). I use this to monitor my sites for uptime.

Comment: thank you it sure is a good service